# How do I stop all running sequences in UVM?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

Is there a way to stop all running sequences during a simulation(say when you get a reset) ?
Is there a way to dump the a list of all running sequences at  particular time during simulation ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. sequencer_h.stop_sequences() See https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/Sequences/Stopping for what you need to do and what you need to be careful about with an active driver.

There is nothing built-in to the UVM to dump all the running sequences, but if you are using Questa, there is a debugging command "uvm findsequences" that will list them out for you.

Comment: What is `sequencer_h` ? Did you mean calling `stop_sequences` on all running sequencers ? I don't have access to the link you have posted.

Comment: When I do `sqr.stop_sequences`, I get this `UVM_FATAL`. Can you please provide any hints on how to debug this? Error: `Item_done() called with no outstanding requests. Each call to item_done() must be paired with a previous call to get_next_item().`

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit `received_item_done` in every sequence. You can wait for the `posedge` of this bit before stopping any particular sequence. You can use the `current_grabber` function from the sequencer base class to get a handle of the sequence which currently has a lock or grab on the sequence.

`stop_sequences` will stop the sequence currently loaded on a sequencer.